# Kotlin: higher-order function taking vararg lamba-with-receiver, where the receiver takes arguments

Tags: kotlin, lambda, builder, kotlin-dsl

I am trying to wrap a hierarchy of Java builders in a Kotlin type-safe builder. The hierarchy consists of the following builders (and their targets):

- FigureBuilder (Figure)
- LayoutBuilder (Layout)
- TraceBuilder (Trace)

In Java, FigureBuilder has one method that takes a Layout, and another that take n traces, using a varargs method called addTraces():

```
addTraces(Trace... traces)
```

The assembly process in Java is basically

```
Figure f = Figure.builder()
   .layout(
       Layout.builder()
           .title("title")
           .build())
   .addTraces(
       ScatterTrace.builder()
           .name("my series")
           .build())
   .build();
```

In Kotlin, I have code that creates the figure builder and the layout builder, but I am stuck on the trace builder. My code so far looks like this:

```
 val figure = figure {
            layout {title("Wins vs BA")}

            addTraces(
                ScatterTrace.builder(x, y)
                    .name("Batting avg.").build()
            )
        }


fun figure(c: FigureBuilder.() -> Unit) : Figure {
    val builder = Figure.builder()
    c(builder)
    return builder.build()
}

fun FigureBuilder.layout(c: Layout.LayoutBuilder.() -> Unit) {
    layout(Layout.builder().apply(c).build())
}

// won't compile: ScatterTrace.builder() requires 2 args
fun FigureBuilder.traces(vararg c: ScatterTrace.ScatterBuilder.() -> Unit) {
    c.forEach {
        val builder = ScatterTrace.builder()
        it(builder)
        addTraces(builder.build())
    }
}
```

I'm not at all sure the last function will work if I can get it to compile, but the immediate blocking issue is that ScatterTrace.builder() takes two arguments and 
I cannot figure out how to pass them into the lambda.

Thanks very much

Comment: Have you tried to spread the ScatterTrace.ScatterBuilder args via spread operator (*)?

Comment: @BrandonMcAnsh. Sorry, I don't really know what that is. I will google it, but to be clear, IDK how to get even a single argument to a constructor inside the traces() method (or any other higher level function that takes a lambda-with-receivers as its argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's strange that in Java you can create `ScatterTrace.builder` without arguments but in Kotlin you need two arguments to construct it. Maybe it will be better to apply traces one by one?

```
fun FigureBuilder.traces(x: Int, y: Int, c: ScatterTrace.ScatterBuilder.() -> Unit) {
    val builder = ScatterTrace.builder(x, y)
    c(builder)
    addTraces(builder.build())
}

val figure = figure {
    layout { title("Wins vs BA") }

    addTraces(
        trace(x, y) { name("Batting avg.") },
        trace(x, y) { name("Batting avg. 2") },
        trace(x, y) { name("Batting avg. 3") }
    )
}
```

Comment: I can't do it in Java either. The issue is that the Java API has required arguments in the constructors for that class. The question behind the question is that if I want to do this kind of nice type-safe-builder in Kotlin for a class I don't control, am I limited to things with default (no arg) constructors?

Comment: Anyway, you have to pass these constructor parameters. From my point of view, functions like `fun fun(builder parameters) { builder receiver lambda }` are good enough.

Comment: This is a good solution. Combined with the spread operator suggestion from Brandon, it's got me 90% of where I want to be. The only issue is having to use parens for traces() rather than {}. It's an irregularity in my api that I would like to avoid, but I'll accept this as the answer if I can't come up with something better. I know other DSLs solve this somehow. kotlinx.html, for example, manages to put an arbitrary number of divs inside a body tag without wrapping the divs in parens.

Answer (score 1):

```
fun FigureBuilder.traces(vararg c: ScatterTrace.ScatterBuilder.() -> Unit) {
    addTraces(
            *c.map {
                val builder = ScatterTrace.builder()
                builder.build()
            }.toTypedArray()
    )
}
```

should do what you are looking for with your vararg requirement.